# SSH permission denied error on ssh to localhost, freshly reset SSH keys

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm running into (what I think is) a very odd situation.

I was having some trouble connecting a specific user to another host via SSH. So, I thought I'd try a simple re-initialization of all SSH keys for this user. So, I did:

```
cd ~/.ssh
rm *
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

Which I thought would have totally reset my SSH connection. But now, when I do:

```
ssh localhost
```

I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

If I do:

```
ssh -v localhost
```

I see:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'lkushwaha'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:lLEq3WpI9BbwnU8WXoeWp0s/DFJr7UwmnnC1nUA4KKc
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1074)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1074)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lkushwaha/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I don't understand what's going on. It seems to me, a simple ssh to localhost should work just fine.

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any hints in the `sshd` logs on the server?

Comment: There were....permissions on .ssh directory and file in it were fine, but permissions on $HOME were too relaxed.  It's working now, thanks!